# Can I prevent clang-format from formatting some (generated) files?

Tags: clang-format

Some of the C source files in my project are generated. They obviously are not formatted to the standard in the `.clang-format` file.

If I just `clang-format` or `git clang-format` that generate source is re-formatted causing unnecessary clutter in the commits.

Is there a way to specify that some files should be ignored by `clang-format`?

Answer (score 1):

In the default implementation of the git clang-format there is no flag or something to ignore autogenerated files .
but it can be **achieved** by implementing a wrapper script ( I will show how to do that in bash)  that will clean the files that you don't want to format and then using the git clang-format.

**for example:**

1.first of all lets say your generated files include a pattern for example auto_gen or generated .

2.define a regex exp for the auto generated patterns in our example
it can be : `pattern_to_exclude_from_clang='.*auto_gen|.*generated'`

3.define allfiles = `git diff --name-only`   - this will give you all
the files that your commit change.

4.filter out generated files allfiles ( exclude generated files)

5.run `git clang-format --diff -- ${wantedfiles[@]}`

so the final script can be :

```
#!/bin/bash
pattern_to_exclude_from_clang='.*auto_gen|.*generated'
allfiles=`git diff --name-only`
files_array=($allfiles)

for i in "${!files_array[@]}":
do
   if [[ "${files_array[$i]}" =~ $pattern_to_exclude_from_clang ]];then
       printf "%s %s" "${files_array[$i]" "this file will be skipped by clang"
       unset files_array[$i]
   fi
done

git clang-format --diff -- ${allfiles[@]}
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in line 9: you are missing the closing curly bracket `}`. So it should be `"${files_array[$i]}"`

Comment: also getting this error: `clang-ignore.sh: line 9: 2:: syntax error in expression (error token is ":")
git: 'clang-format' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`